# Cplex Objective Function Error

Tags: java, cplex

I declare a variable `linObj` as `IloNumExpr`, and I have 4 loops (loop element i,j,k and l)  where each time I add to this variable a summation of two other variable like:

```
linObj = cplex.sum(linObj, cplex.sum(s[i][j][j][k],s[i][j][l][k])
```

When loops are closed I declare `linObj` as the objective function.

Now, I have an error called `ilog.cplex.MultiObjectiveException`.

Comment: As you can read here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefjavacplex%2Fhtml%2Filog%2Fcplex%2FMultipleObjectiveException.html the ilog.cplex.MultipleObjectiveException is thrown by an attempt to add more than one objective to a model. Can you please provide complete code so that we can figure out what's going out there?

Answer (score 1):

With that exception you're probably doing something like this inside your loops:

```
linObj = cplex.sum(linObj, cplex.sum(s[i][j][j][k],s[i][j][l][k]);
cplex.addMinimize(linObj);
```

Thus getting multiple objectives.
Only call `cplex.addMinimize(linObj);` after the loops and you should only get one objective.

Moreover, you should consider changing your code to:

```
IloLinearNumExpr linObj = cplex.linearNumExpr();
/*loops*/

linObj.addTerm(1, cplex.sum(s[i][j][j][k],s[i][j][l][k]);

/*after loops*/
cplex.addMinimize(linObj);
```

Hope this helps